# Xamarin Forms Pinch to zoom event not raised

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I've been trying to implement a page with a WebView and do some custom code in pinch to zoom.
But the event "PinchUpdated" of the "PinchGestureRecognizer" will not be raised.

Page:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <WebView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="https://google.com/" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    private PinchGestureRecognizer pinchRecognizer = new PinchGestureRecognizer();

    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.pinchRecognizer.PinchUpdated += this.HandlePinchUpdated;
    }

    private void HandlePinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

When I set a break point in the event it will not be hit.
Not in emulator or on a real device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From the posted code, it seems that the 'pinchRecognizer' was not added to the page or the webview. Try to use the code like `image.GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);` to attach the gesture to the view. Check the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pinch

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what you're saying, I think you're problem is in how events are handled against webviews. By default if you try to pinch zoom inside the frame of the webview, it will only affect the html in the webview.
If you are not intending on interacting with the webview, try placing a mask (BoxView) over the top of the whole Webview, and then apply the pinch zoom to the mask box.

Comment: Okay, but this would mean the user could not interact with the web view.
I need only the pinch to zoom event.
My use case is that the app will show a fixed web site that is responsive so the zoom will not be used.
With the pinch I want the user to be able to change to a configuration page.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get what you're saying now. Unfortunately because you are essentially making a Hybrid app, all your interactions will have to be handled via JavaScript in the webview. To communicate to the app, you will need to use a Hybrid Web view, something not supported in Xamarin yet, but can be built. Here's a great doc on how to do it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This seems a little overkill for my use case.
I will think about another way to get into the configuration :)

Comment: No problem. If you are looking to display jsut some simple html you could also jsut use a label. You will be surprised how much html it can take.

<Label Text="YOUR HTML" TextType="Html" />